# How to access controls with the same name on different pages from a common class

Tags: c#, asp.net

Warning: newbie - probably pretty obvious from the question.

My site will have multiple pages that have textboxes that I want to validate and total into a label.

For example: Page1.aspx, Page2.aspx, Page3.aspx will each have the same series of textboxes named Texbox1, Textbox2, Textbox3 and Textbox4 with a label named LabelTotal.

I want to have a common class that when called from any PageX.aspx.cs (X=1,2,3) will validate those textbox inputs and put the sum in the label on that page. The controls on each page will have the same names so the method in the common class will know the control names, but just need to know which page to use.
There’s actually many more than 4 textboxes, but I’m just trying to simplify it.

Can someone provide a simple outline of how I’d set this up? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking to wrap those up in a custom control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zt27tfhy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: If you call that common class from the code behind of the page, and pass the inputs to the common class ( not sure if thats what your doing) it will use the controls from the page, so it will know which ones to validate.